# error on running testng gropus with beanshell through maven command

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, beanshell

I have a setup like below. while running the tests with the `-Dgroups`, i get the below error. what is wrong with my setup? I need to pass which test groups to be run through my maven command. Any help on this is much appreciable.

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="Utilities.CustomTestListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="RegressionTests">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                    <![CDATA[whatGroup = System.getProperty("groups");
                    groups.containsKey(whatGroup);
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="Tests.test_sampleTests"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**sampleTests.java**

```
@Test(groups = {"low"})
public void samplePositiveTest() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Test run under low group");
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache-extras.beanshell</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${testngFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!--<groups>low</groups>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

maven execution command

```
mvn clean install -Dbrowser="chrome" -Denv="qa" -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="regress.xml" -Dgroups="low"
```

error on execution

```
[ERROR] Please refer to /opt/TestProjects/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:733)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
```

Comment: any idea to make this work? any help is much appreciable please.